# Creating a list of dicts from Pandas df

Tags: dictionary, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe of the the form

```
0   x     y    z
1   .5   .1    4
2   .6   .2    5
```

I want to convert this into a list of dicts for the first two cols, namely
[{'x':0.5, 'y':0.1}, {'x':0.6, 'y':0.2}.....]

I can write a loop and do it the dumb way, is there a better faster way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [iterrows](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) for that.  This lets you iterate over the rows as `Series`, not dicts, but that is pretty similar (e.g. has `iteritems()`, `__getitem__`, etc).

If you must have use dicts, you can easily convert each `Series` to dict, using the `to_dict()` method.

For example:

```
list_of_dicts = list( row.to_dict() for key, row in df.iterrows() )
```

Comment: @ganeshreddy, sure. I added it.

Comment: this also gives me an error:tuple object has no attribute to_dict

Comment: @ganeshreddy, ah, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Use `to_dict(orient='records')` with `orient=records` and is faster.

```
In [2]: df[['x', 'y']].to_dict(orient='records')
Out[2]:
[{'x': 0.5, 'y': 0.1}, {'x': 0.6, 'y': 0.2}]
```

---

**Timings**

```
In [8]: df.shape
Out[8]: (10000, 4)

In [9]: %timeit df[['x', 'y']].to_dict(orient='records')
10 loops, best of 3: 68.4 ms per loop

In [10]: %timeit df[['x','y']].to_dict('index').values()
1 loop, best of 3: 570 ms per loop 

In [11]: %timeit list(row.to_dict() for key, row in df[['x', 'y']].iterrows())
1 loop, best of 3: 575 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`to_dict()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method. Let `yourdata.csv` be your data in .csv format:

```
df = pd.read_csv('yourdata.csv')

d = df[['x','y']].to_dict('index').values()
```

should work. It returns:

```
[{'y': 0.1, 'x': 0.5}, {'y': 0.2, 'x': 0.6}]
```

Comment: I am getting 'valuerror:outtype index not understood'

Comment: Does this solution preserve order or rows?

Comment: I guess that would be a nice to have.

Comment: @shx2 I think so, since the 'index' arg works as {index -> {column -> value}.

Comment: @ganeshreddy for me it works, I've just imported your dataframe with `pd.read_csv('yourdata.csv')`.

Comment: valuError:outtype index not understood

Comment: @ganeshreddy which version of pandas are you running? As I said, I cannot reproduce your error.

Comment: 0.13.1 is the version

Comment: @ganeshreddy try updating to the latest 0.17.